# how to use Math.round() in java for getting =ROUND(A8/1000,2)* 1000 (excel formula) output

Tags: java, math, excel-formula, rounding

I have a value `7075.5` I need to get the output as `7080`. I need to apply the below Excel formula to get this output.

```
=ROUND(A8/1000, 2) * 1000
```

how to accomplish this formula/requirement using java?
    I tried few but I am far away from the expected output.

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double e = 7075.9;
        System.out.println("Rounding 7075.5="+Math.round(e*1000)/1000); 
    }
}
```

can anybody please help to get this done in Java? please refer the excel formula given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you dividing by `1000` when you only want to round off the last digit?

You can use

```
System.out.println("Rounding 7075.5="+Math.round(e/10)*10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It was fine you used 1000 for dividing and multiplying in excel because there you had the scope to pass extra parameter for number digit after decimal.

You could have even used foll in excel

```
=ROUND(A8/10,0)*10
```

For Java

```
 Math.round(e/10)*10
```